# A question about numbers with a certain property

Tags: induction, recursion, integers

Find (if exists) a subset of the non negative integers $X$ such that for every non negative integer $n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ there is exactly one solution of the form $a+2b=n$ with $a,b \in X$

I have "conjectured" those numbers are of the form:

$2 \cdot 3^{m-1} -1$ and $2 \cdot 3^{m-1} -2 $ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ but I can't prove it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be any nonnegative integer.

Using the base $4$ expansion of $n$, we have

$$n=\sum_{i=0}^k d_i\cdot 4^i,\text{ where each $d_i$ is one of $0,1,2$, or $3$. }$$

Now define $a_i=d_i\% 2$ (here $\%$ is the mod (remainder) operator); and define $b_i=\lfloor\frac{d_i}{2}\rfloor$

Note: (1) For all $i$, $a_i+2b_i=d_i$; and (2) For all $i$, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are each either $0$ or $1$.

Define $a=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\cdot 4^i$ and $b=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^k b_i\cdot 4^i$.

We have that $n=a+2b$.

Thus we may take $X$ to be the set of nonnegative integers that can be written as a sum of distinct powers of $4$. Note: this includes the empty sum, $0$. That is, $0\in X$.

So $X=\{0,1,4,5,16,17,20,21,64,65,68,69,80,\dots\}$

For example, let's look at $n=147$. We have $147=3+0\cdot 4+1\cdot 4^2+2\cdot 4^3$. We take $a=1+4^2=17$ and $b=1+4^3=65$.  An, as expected, $n=a+2b$.

Comment: Thank you! will look deeper into this as I get home. I wonder if this can be generalized as $m \cdot a + l \cdot b = n$

Comment: Also, what is the intuition behind your solution?

Comment: @Victor Kolobov: I started out (with no intuition) trying to build $X$ from the ground up--need 0, need 1, avoid 2, etc. By the time I got to 0, 1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, 21 I saw the pattern of sums of every other power of 2 (I was thinking binary), which soon got me thinking of powers of 4.  The $a+2b$ condition made me realize that the base 4 digits (0, 1, 2, 3) could be written as $0+2\cdot 0$, $1+2\cdot 0$, $0+2\cdot 1$, $1+2\cdot 1$. This means that $a+2b$ let's us write any base $4$ digit and place value as $a+2b$ just using the place value.  (E.g., $3\cdot 4^3=4^3+2\cdot 4^3$.)

Comment: Ah it makes much more sense now, thx, it is a very clever solution